# How to disable invalidate()?

Tags: android, invalidation

At first my programm looks like this:

[image]

But when i am moving the picture around the screen programm turns to:

[image]

Red graph is random-generated in onDraw method. So i want to draging picture around and have static background that not inavalidates while im moving picture.

here is my code:
**Custom View:**
    package com.graph.base;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Random;

public class CustomView extends View
{
Random random=new Random();
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    Path path=new Path();
    path.moveTo(10, 10);
    for (float i=0.5f; i<=140; i+=10)
    {
        path.quadTo(10+i*5, 10+random.nextInt(500), 10+(i+10)*5,     10+random.nextInt(500));
    }
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);    
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
package com.graph.base;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
FrameLayout frame;
ImageView image;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Touch happend");
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                image.setPadding((int)event.getX(),     (int)event.getY(), 0, 0);
                break;
            }

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void invalidateButton_Click (View v)
{
    frame.invalidate();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're drawing random lines onto your canvas. This code is called each time the screen is invalidated. If you want to keep the drawing from changing, then set a bitmap into a canvas and draw into the bitmap. In your onDraw() method you'll then draw the bitmap onto the canvas.

```
// Outside of onDraw()
Bitmap bmDest = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas mycanvas = new Canvas(bmDest);
// Do your drawing on the canvas outside of the onDraw() method
```

In onDraw(), you'll simply do this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmDest, x, y, null);
```

Comment: cant post code here, but ive got error, when try to rewrite all my onDraw method to the constructor of my customView. I think, that when i create my view, i generate graph, put it onto the bitmap-canvas and then draw, but ive got a lot errors.

Comment: A quick view of your code looks okay except for the drawBitmap(). The 2 numbers are the upper left corner x/y, not the width/height. You've not shown me what the errors are, so I can't comment. You really need to properly design the drawing/painting logic to work as you want.

Comment: I cant understand how it works. Cant understand difference between using only canvas and canvas+bitmap. Cant understand how to use bitmap in general. I wrote the code, it have no errors, but it does not work. [code](http://pastebin.com/xuq0vf97)

Comment: Maybe I'll post my thoughts? Canvas - a piece of paper, the bitmap - the skin, which we do all the same thing on paper, but then we can put into the bank and use anywhere? We put skin on paper by constructor canvas=new Canvas(bitmap), then we painting on the paper like canvas.drawPath, but our bitmap in that moment is painting too? And we have the same canvas, but in another format? Dont know, how it explain, cause my english is bad.

Comment: Android's GUI, similar to many graphics systems, has the notion of invalidating the display when something needs to change. If your current view has the ability to scroll, scrolling the display will invalidate it and cause the onDraw() method to be called. Your code is then responsible for repainting the display. If you draw randomly on each onDraw() call it will look disorganized when you scroll the view. You need to retain your graphics information in some form and a bitmap is a good way to hold onto your drawing. The bitmap can be drawn on whenever you want and then repainted in a new pos.

Comment: Yes, i understand, that onDraw() calling when i do something, but i cant understand how i can save my data from screen. Logic is not a problem, its simple and clear, code - problem.

Comment: It appears that logic is still the problem. Your paper analogy is confusing. It's really quite simple. The bitmap object can hold onto an image in memory. It will retain your drawing instructions. The current view can ask to be painted at any time. You simply draw your bitmap onto that canvas when asked to do so by onDraw().

Comment: Find it!
Error canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), null);
But i need to: canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
So, еhanks, you saved me from sleepless nights.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should not "disable invalidate" but really do call "invalidate"...

In

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            image.setPadding((int)event.getX(),     (int)event.getY(), 0, 0);
            // here call frame.invalidate(Rect dirty), with dirty set to where the image was previously
            break;
        }
```

Note that if your custom View draws "Randomly", then you can get a Bitmap with the cached version and draw from that (blit copy)